# Django - Sending OPTIONS request second time will append body data to request method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.5, django-cors-headers

The issue is when there's content inside body with OPTIONS method, the second request will always fail with message **Method Not Allowed**. Printed the log and showed that the method became `"{"username":"test","password":"test"}POST /member/login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 111`. Problem is when the server has restarted, the first OPTIONS request will pass normally. Have tried with only POST and it works fine. Only OPTIONS has this issue.

ENV details: python:3.6.5, django:2.1.3, drf:3.9.0, django-cors-headers:2.4.0

views.py(Only show the decorations cause it didn't go inside the block):

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def member_login(request):
    pass
```

middlewares:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Request method: **OPTIONS** and **POST**

Request header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://google.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type
```

Request body:

```
{"username":"superuser","password":"pass1234"}
```

After sending OPTIONS request for 2 times:

```
INFO 2018-12-25 02:26:03,585 "OPTIONS /member/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
WARNING 2018-12-25 02:26:10,180 Method Not Allowed: /member/login/
WARNING 2018-12-25 02:26:10,182 "{"username":"superuser","password":"pass1234"}OPTIONS /member/login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 98
```

After getting error with method not allowed, cannot send any other request to the api. It will always return **Method Not Allowed** even it's the different method I'm using.

```
WARNING 2018-12-25 02:30:57,939 Method Not Allowed: /member/login/
WARNING 2018-12-25 02:30:57,940 "{"username":"superuser","password":"pass1234"}POST /member/login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 95
WARNING 2018-12-25 02:30:58,603 Method Not Allowed: /member/login/
WARNING 2018-12-25 02:30:58,603 "{"username":"superuser","password":"pass1234"}POST /member/login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 95
WARNING 2018-12-25 02:30:59,684 Method Not Allowed: /member/login/
WARNING 2018-12-25 02:30:59,685 "{"username":"superuser","password":"pass1234"}POST /member/login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 95
```

Tried with the older version of Django. This issue didn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to `Django>=2.1.5` will fix this. This is due to this issue: [HTTP server doesn't clear previous request data in keep-alive connection](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30015)

The issue was that the implementation of WSGI server for `runserver` was not consuming request content when there was an `OPTIONS` request. And with a keep-alive connection, the remaining data got read as content for the subsequent request.